# Get text value in a RadRichTextBox

Tags: silverlight, telerik, rad-controls

I have a RadRichTextBox in my Silverlight project which is setup to use basic formatting.  Quite frankly I am just using it instead of Textbox in order to take advantage of the Spellchecker feature.

```
<telerik:RadRichTextBox AllowScaling="False" DocumentInheritsDefaultStyleSettings="True" Height="82" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" IsContextMenuEnabled="True" IsSelectionMiniToolBarEnabled="False" IsSpellCheckingEnabled="True" Margin="32,61,0,0" Name="radRichTextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Width="202" />
```

How would I access the contents of radRichTextBox1 as just text with newlines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to simply create a provider and extract the contents as follows:

```
var provider = new TxtFormatProvider();
var result = provider.Export(radRichTextBox1.Document);
```